# How can I run the web page of my web application in an android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, wampserver

I created an android application via html5 and php now I convert this web application to an android application and I set the url address in my java code as follow

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://localhost/OacaApp/Interface.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

which is the interface of my application that I want to see it from my android application 
but when I run the emulator I got this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Wlr.png

Do any one can help me please to fix the problem because when I run my browser from the emulator I can access to the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run it through 'localhost', which acts like your phone is hosting the website. Put the public IP and open the port, or switch to Web Hosting. Also, local IP of the Server should work (192.168.1.xxx)

Comment: I checked th cmd than ip config my IPV4 is   http://197.28.174.31/ whe I put it in the browser it gives me the page of my wampserver what should I do exactly specify just the ip address means like this http://197.28.174.31/ or like this http://197.28.174.31/OacaApp/Interface.html

Comment: Then put that IP instead of 'localhost' part in the URL

Comment: now it's working but not all because in my interface I have a button when I click in it it must appear another page and this .php must select data from mysql and display it on this page with the web application it's working but now no Thanks a lot